# Domain level privacy in Google Drive for file

Tags: google-drive-api

I want to display file (which is stored on google drive) in iframe, but file should be displayed on our website's domain only. I don't want that anyone who has the URL of file can have access to file.

I am giving file permission on uploading file like:

```
public static Permission FilePermissions(DriveService service, String fileId)
{
    Permission Permission = new Permission();
    Permission.Type = "anyone";
    Permission.Role = "reader";

    try
    {
        return service.Permissions.Create(Permission, fileId).Execute();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("An error occurred: " + e.Message);
    }
    return null;
}
```

And I am displaying file like:

```
<iframe id="iframe1" runat="server" width="100%" height="600px" src=""https://drive.google.com/file/d/{fileID}/preview"></iframe>
```

This code works but anyone can grab URL from iframe and have access to file. Is there anyway we can impose permissions to only allow access to file if it is being loaded from an iframe within specific website domain name (e.g. http://www.company.com)?

Comment: Instead of giving reading access to anyone, you can give it only to certain users or only to your domain.

Comment: @ziganotschka domain level File permission in Google Drive is related to domain of email, but I want it restricted to domain of website.

Comment: Would [Publish to the Web](https://support.google.com/a/users/answer/9308870?hl=en) be a solution for you?

Comment: @ziganotschka No... I have to give access to certain people who has subscribed to the content. But they can find URL of file from iframe and can share with others who hasn't subscription.

Comment: I can only think of the option of sharing the file exclusively with specified viewers (that have to sign in with the email you share the file with) whereby the copy and download options would be disabled. For a `Publish to WEb` view, you can embed it into an Apps Script WebApp and intergrate the WebApp URL into the iframe - once again specifying in the Web App deployment options who is allowed to open the WebApp URL.